# Trying to delete the records from a table if that does not have atleast one row of required status with in a yearquarter

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table emp

```
empid   yearquarter status  price
101      20011       A       30
101      20011       A       40
102      20021       A       80
103      20021       A       90
103      20021       A       100
104      20031       B       20
104      20031       A       50
```

AFTER DELETION
THE EMP TABLE SHOULD BE LEFT WITH

OUTPUT

```
empid   yearquarter status  price
104      20031       B        20
104      20031       A        50
```

WITH IN YEARQUARTER IF THE TABLE DONT HAVE STATUS='B' NEED TO DELETE THEM

I AM TRYING TO USE

```
delete from EMP  where status not in ('a')
group by yearquarter
```

BUT IT IS GIVING ERROR AND NOT DISPLAYING THE DESIRED RESULT

Comment: hint:  WHERE NOT EXISTS()

Comment: group by is for select, no delete

Comment: Why are you yelling at everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're asking...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Emp', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Emp;

CREATE TABLE #Emp (
    empid INT NOT NULL,
    yearquarter INT NOT NULL,
    [status] CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    price MONEY NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #Emp (empid, yearquarter, status, price) VALUES 
    (101, 20011, 'A', 30),
    (101, 20011, 'A', 40),
    (102, 20021, 'A', 80),
    (103, 20021, 'A', 90),
    (103, 20021, 'A', 100),
    (104, 20031, 'B', 20),
    (104, 20031, 'A', 50);

--pre-delete select...
SELECT * FROM #Emp e;

--============================================

DELETE e1
FROM
    #Emp e1
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 
                    *
                FROM
                    #Emp e2
                WHERE 
                    e1.empid = e2.empid
                    AND e1.yearquarter = e2.yearquarter
                    AND e2.[status] = 'B'
                )

--post-delete select...
SELECT * FROM #Emp e;
```

Results...

```
empid       yearquarter status price
----------- ----------- ------ ---------------------
101         20011       A      30.00
101         20011       A      40.00
102         20021       A      80.00
103         20021       A      90.00
103         20021       A      100.00
104         20031       B      20.00
104         20031       A      50.00

empid       yearquarter status price
----------- ----------- ------ ---------------------
104         20031       B      20.00
104         20031       A      50.00
```

Comment: Looking to the question. Not sure if employee is relevant on the delete. If that is the case this is the answer. If only need to know the yearquarter with `B` then @Eli give a simple solution.

Comment: I suppose it's a matter of interpretation... You may very well be correct. In either case, the NOT EXISTS will work equally well. The NOT IN will be limited to a single column comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `GROUP BY` clause in conjunction with a `DELETE` statement.

You would want to use a nested `NOT IN` clause such as the following:

```
DELETE
FROM EMP 
WHERE YEARQUARTER NOT IN (
    SELECT YEARQUARTER
    FROM EMP
    WHERE STATUS = 'B'
)
```